# Error with 'XRJulia' when passing a large matrix

Tags: r, julia

It seems that the R packages **JuliaConnectoR** and **JuliaCall** have some problems with the latest Julia (v1.9.1).

Well, this is not my question. I try then to use the **XRJulia** package.

When I try to inverse a 3x3 matrix, it works fine:

```r
library(XRJulia)

A <- toeplitz(3:1)
B <- juliaEval("inv(%s)", A)
juliaGet(B)
#      [,1]  [,2] [,3] 
# [1,] 0.625 -0.5 0.125
# [2,] -0.5  1    -0.5 
# [3,] 0.125 -0.5 0.625
```

But when I try to inverse a 1000x1000 matrix, I get the error *'\U' used without hex digits in character string*:

```
set.seed(9392927)
N <- 1e3L
A <- matrix(rpois(N^2L, lambda = 10), N)
B <- juliaEval("inv(%s)", A)
# Error: '\U' used without hex digits in character string (<text>:1:24)
```

Would you know why and how to do?

Answer (score 1):

I don't think **JuliaConnectoR** has problems with Julia 1.9.1 as
the following lines work with R 4.3.1 and Julia 1.9.1 w/o problems:

```
library(JuliaConnectoR)
juliaSetupOk()
## [1] TRUE

set.seed(9392927); N <- 1e3L
A <- matrix(rpois(N^2L, lambda = 10), N)

system.time(Ainv <- juliaCall("inv", A))
##    user  system elapsed 
##   1.693   4.097   6.150
```

Just to mention: in pure Julia, inverting a 1000x1000-matrix of integers takes about 0.05-0.10 seconds (on my computer), so most of the runtime is overhead of integrating the two systems.

Comment: Are you on Linux ? On Windows it takes 85 seconds!

Comment: Linux system with a few years on its belt:  3.9s elapsed, 0.9 user and 2.8 system.

Comment: On Linux. I assume most of your long running time comes from XRJUlia, not from Windows; XRJulia is still more like a "demo system". I can't check because for me loading XRJulia generates an error.

Comment: @HansW. 85 seconds with JuliaConnectoR. And the developer of JuliaConnectoR has also tried on Windows, he obtained 23 seconds.

Answer (score 0):

I've found, one has to set an option:

```r
juliaOptions(largeObject = 10000000L)
```

But the matrix inversion is incredibly slow.